# Gojs inserting an element to canvas

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm using this template https://gojs.net/latest/samples/seatingChart.html

I want to insert an element like this [image]

Base on 3 people, we sum 30 minutes.

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want a feature to drag & drop node from Palette?

Comment: You can see the blue element that's what I want to insert to the canvas. For example, If drag and drop a person from Pallete to the canvas, the blue element will be inserted to the canvas by code.